# I do not know the key '/tikz/insert path'

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, diagrams, compiling

Trying to compile this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]

% A path that follows the edges of the current page
\tikzstyle{reverseclip}=[insert path={(current page.north east) --
(current page.south east) --
(current page.south west) --
  (current page.north west) --
  (current page.north east)}
]

\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (1,0);
\coordinate (C) at (1,1);

\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox} % To make sure our clipping path does not mess up the         placement of the picture
\path [clip] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle [reverseclip];
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}

\draw[thick] (A) circle (2mm);
\draw[thick] (B) circle (2mm);    
\draw[thick] (C) circle (2mm);   

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But I got the error: 
    I do not know the key '/tikz/insert path'

My Tikz version is tikz.code.tex,v 1.76 2010/10/13 09:20:31
Could you help me?

Comment: This seems to compile fine for me. I am using the same version (updated TeXLive 2010), so most likely one of the other tikz libraries need updating.

Comment: It doesn't compile with TeX Live 2009; so probably the upgrading of TikZ has not been done properly. The key `insert path` is indeed in `tikz.code.tex`.

Comment: Thanks, I solved installing the latest version of Tikz, taken from here (http://bulldog.duhs.duke.edu/~faheem/debian/pgf_2.10-0_all.deb).

Answer (score 2):

The key `insert path` is indeed in `tikz.code.tex`.

The document doesn't compile with TeX Live 2009; so probably the upgrading of TikZ has not been done properly.